# Поведение сборщика мусора по отношению к структурам

Tags: c#, структуры, сборщик-мусора, производительность

Недавно прочитал статью [Предельная производительность: C#](http://habrahabr.ru/post/165729/)

> Из-за того, что структуры хранятся в stack’е, они не требуют сборки мусора

поясните пожалуйста, это действительно так?

Comment: сборки то они требуют, но компилятор может вставить код, который очистит их автоматически по выходу с метода. В большинстве случаев это очень дешево (просто поправить указатель стека - одна арифметическая операция, несколько тактов процессора). Но вот если у структуры есть поля, которые  не являются примитивными типами (то есть поля типа класс), то здесь не все так однозначно.

Comment: > сборки то они требуют

Это относится к Java. Если речь именно о локальных переменных.

Comment: К.О. в java нет структур.

Comment: > в java нет структур.

Тьфу. Ведь да.

Тем не менее, память под локальные переменные-структуры выделяется именно в стеке.

Comment: Почитайте Эрика, он хороший (к тому, же, один из ключевых разработчиков языка): [раз](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx), [два](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two.aspx)

Comment: Кстати, статья ужасна. Она рекомендует очень грязные методы оптимизации, которые вовсе не обязаны реально работать. Никогда никогда никогда не используйте это в нормальном коде.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Краткое содержание.** Нет, структуры не обязательно хранятся в стеке, а объекты — в куче. Да, с хорошими шансами структура всё же попадёт в стек. Нет, вам не стоит на это рассчитывать, пользоваться этим и пытаться оптимизировать таким образом.

---

На самом деле следует понимать простую вещь: выделение переменной на стеке дешевле, поскольку её можно легко уничтожить, не включая в цикл сборки мусора. Выгода на самом деле только в этом. (Аллокация что на стеке, что в куче — не более, чем увеличение одного указателя, она *очень* быстрая.)

Очевидно, оптимизатор будет размещать в стеке те переменные, которые, как он может доказать, не нужны после смерти текущего фрейма. Часто про структуры можно такое доказать, но не всегда. Например, структура может быть частью объекта класса, и должна умереть вместе с классом. Или метод будет неявно переписан в стиле [продолжений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), например, если это генератор (`yield return` & Co.) или `Task<>` с async/await. Или переменная попала в замыкание некоторой лямбда-функции. И так далее. Но обычно структуры не нужны после отработки метода, так что оптимизатор может вытеснить их в стек.

С другой стороны, про некоторые объекты можно тоже утверждать, что они не нужны после окончания фрейма — и тогда оптимизатор тоже [имеет полное право](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11192) (но не обязанность, конечно) разместить и их на стеке.

Обратите внимание на такую тонкость: если вы возвращаете из метода структуру, вы на самом деле возвращаете её *копию*, поэтому структура, с которой вы работали, может попасть в стек. С классами же не так: они копируются не по значению, а по ссылке, поэтому возвращаемый объект переживает создавшую его функцию, и следовательно не имеет права жить в стеке.

[Использованы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one) [материалы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two) из блога Эрика Липперта, на которые была ссылка выше.

---

Добавлю ещё пару цитат из Эрика:

> Использование стека для локальных переменных-структур — всего лишь оптимизация, которую CLR выполняет для вас. Существенная особенность структур — семантика копирования по значению, а вовсе не то, что в некоторых случаях их уничтожение может быть оптимизировано рантайм-библиотекой.

---

> В подавляющем большинстве программ, выделение и уничтожение локальных переменных не будут критически важным фактором производительности.

---

> Превращение типа, который должен на самом деле быть ссылочным типом, в структуру — это нано-оптимизация, дающая выгоду в пару наносекунд, и вероятно не стоящая того. На вашем месте я бы проводил такую оптимизацию только если данные профилирования покажут, что существует реальная, большая проблема у ваших реальных клиентов, которую можно исправить использованием структур. Не имея таких данных на руках, я всегда бы делал выбор между классами и структурами основываясь на том, представляет ли тип семантически значение или ссылку на что-то. (*То есть, имеет ли объект смысл помимо значения, содержащегося в нём, обладает ли он самостоятельной сущностью* — VladD)

Answer (score 2):

> Из-за того, что структуры хранятся в stack’е, они не требуют сборки мусора
>
> поясните пожалуйста, это действительно так?

Если речь идет о *локальных переменных*, то это действительно так. GC работает с кучей.

Очевидно, что структуры не всегда хранятся в стеке. Например, если какой-то класс содержит поля, являющиеся структурами, то память под них однозначно будет выделена в куче, и, следовательно, будут уничтожаться GC.

P.S.: Если структура содержит управляемые поля, то память под эти поля выделится в куче, а в стеке окажутся лишь ссылки на эти управляемые поля. Довольно логично, но некоторые упускают это из виду.